# How do I hide "index.php" from URL on HAProxy

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, .htaccess, haproxy, varnish

Here I install the `HAProxy-1.7` on linux machine and first get the `http+https` request on HAProxy server which trasfer into varnish cache then apache2 web server handle and respond to client. Please find the flow of whole system as below.

Here, HAproxy, Varnish and Apache web server are installed on single machine.

Flow:

```
---443--> |
          | HAProxy ------>Varnish(8081) ----------> apache2(8080)
---80---> |
```

So here I need to hide `index.php` from URL using HAProxy, Is it possible on HAProxy-1.7 ?

Comment: Is this another "SEO friendly" myth question? Just wondering.

Comment: What is the reason not to do this kind of work in your apache? It is not the work of HAProxy or Varnish to modify URLs just for beauty reasons...